# Wordpress un controlled feed request from different IP

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, feed

I am getting a lot of continuous feed request from different IPs, causing the server to occupy all the RAM. I get the following feed request. Can anyone help me to stop the feed...

```
37.210.162.69 - - [12/Sep/2016:04:34:43 -0400] "GET /category/from-newspapers/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 200 56908 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36"
188.52.101.103 - - [12/Sep/2016:04:35:35 -0400] "GET /category/society/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 500 554 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Lenovo TAB 2 A7-30HC Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Safari/537.36;"
86.96.97.72 - - [12/Sep/2016:04:35:35 -0400] "GET /feed/ HTTP/1.1" 500 554 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; Lenovo A7000-a Build/LRX21M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.121 Mobile Safari/537.36"
113.199.255.115 - - [12/Sep/2016:04:34:24 -0400] "GET /category/society/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 200 56908 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-G7202 Build/LMY48B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36"
94.129.248.98 - - [12/Sep/2016:04:35:34 -0400] "GET /category/society/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 500 554 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-J120F Build/LMY47X; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36"
49.244.190.144 - - [12/Sep/2016:04:35:34 -0400] "GET /category/from-newspapers/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 500 554 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-; SC-06D Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
```

Comment: This is actually a DDoS attack, and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie is there any solution to stop the request? It is causing my database to crash

Comment: This question may be better asked at this SO sister-site [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/). If your server has IPTables installed you can quickly mitigate some of the issue by dropping all incoming requests from the offending IP addresses by issuing commands like so: `iptables -A INPUT -s 37.210.162.69 -j DROP`. You might need to run `service iptables save` after adding the IP addresses for it to take effect.

Comment: All request coming are from different IPS, Cant add all those ips to tables

Answer (score 1):

Hi :) The easiest way to secure your WordPress site that I know of (and used myself on 8 WP sites) is to use the WordFence plugin.

WordFence offers different types of protection and features. Out of the box it might be good, but read the documentation to learn which parameters to set for optimal security.

[WordFence website](https://www.wordfence.com/)